# How to convert Pandas Series of dates string into date objects?

Tags: python, pandas, date, time-series

I have a Pandas data frame and one of the columns, have dates in string format of `YYYY-MM-DD`.

For e.g. : `'2013-10-28'`

At the moment the `dtype` of the column is `object`.

How do I convert the column values to Pandas date format?

Answer (score 138, accepted):

Use [astype](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html)

```
In [31]: df
Out[31]: 
   a        time
0  1  2013-01-01
1  2  2013-01-02
2  3  2013-01-03

In [32]: df['time'] = df['time'].astype('datetime64[ns]')

In [33]: df
Out[33]: 
   a                time
0  1 2013-01-01 00:00:00
1  2 2013-01-02 00:00:00
2  3 2013-01-03 00:00:00
```

Comment: Nice - thank you - how do I get rid of the 00:00:00 at the end of each date?

Comment: The pandas timestamp have both date and time. Do you mean convert it into python date object?

Comment: Yep, but I guess the python date object is not supported by Pandas.

Comment: You can convert it by `df['time'] = [time.date() for time in df['time']]`

Comment: what does the [ns] mean, can you make the text string a date and remove the time part of that date?

Comment: @yoshiserry it's nanoseconds, and is the way the dates are stored under the hood once converted properly (epoch-time in nanoseconds).

Comment: Why use this over `pandas.to_datetime()` ?

Answer (score 156):

Essentially equivalent to @waitingkuo, but I would use `pd.to_datetime` here (it seems a little cleaner, and offers some additional functionality e.g. `dayfirst`):

```
In [11]: df
Out[11]:
   a        time
0  1  2013-01-01
1  2  2013-01-02
2  3  2013-01-03

In [12]: pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
Out[12]:
0   2013-01-01 00:00:00
1   2013-01-02 00:00:00
2   2013-01-03 00:00:00
Name: time, dtype: datetime64[ns]

In [13]: df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])

In [14]: df
Out[14]:
   a                time
0  1 2013-01-01 00:00:00
1  2 2013-01-02 00:00:00
2  3 2013-01-03 00:00:00
```

---

**Handling `ValueError`s**
If you run into a situation where doing

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
```

Throws a

```
ValueError: Unknown string format
```

That means you have invalid (non-coercible) values. If you are okay with having them converted to `pd.NaT`, you can add an `errors='coerce'` argument to `to_datetime`:

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], errors='coerce')
```

Comment: Hi Guys, @AndyHayden 
can you remove the time part from the date? I don't need that part?

Comment: In pandas' 0.13.1 the trailing 00:00:00s aren't displayed.

Comment: and what about in other versions, how do we remove / and or not display them?

Comment: I don't think this can be done in a nice way, there is discussion to add date_format like float_format (which you've seen). I recommend upgrading anyway.

Comment: my problem is my date is in this format... 41516.43, and I get this error. I would expect it to return something like 2014-02-03 in the new column?! 

THE ERROR: #convert date values in the "load_date" column to dates

budget_dataset['date_last_load'] = pd.to_datetime(budget_dataset['load_date'])

budget_dataset

-c:2: SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_index,col_indexer] = value instead

Comment: @yoshiserry if the date isn't being converted properly that sounds like a different problem. Could you post this as a separate question, tricky to diagnose here.

Comment: yeah its a numerical representation of a date, but it has two decimal places. Like 41516.426 is actually = 30/08/2013  10:13:26 AM, I'd like first to be able to return the (date and time), and then i'd like to split them into two columns.

Comment: **If more than 1 datetime columns conversion**:`df[['col1', 'col2']].apply(pd.to_datetime, axis=0)`

Comment: @yoshiserry, is the date `41516.43` from Excel?  This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38454403/13608599

Comment: Seems a better answer to me. Specially, because of controlling how the strings are parsed (`dayfirst`, `yearfirst`, etc.). With `astype`, doesn't seem to provide such control in a easy way.

Answer (score 47):

I imagine a lot of data comes into Pandas from CSV files, in which case you can simply convert the date during the initial CSV read:

`dfcsv = pd.read_csv('xyz.csv', parse_dates=[0])` where the 0 refers to the column the date is in.
You could also add `, index_col=0` in there if you want the date to be your index.

See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

You can also select column(s) to parse by name rather than position, e.g. `parse_dates=['thedate']`

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I needed. The documentation has moved, though, you can find it here:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

Answer (score 30):

Now you can do `df['column'].dt.date`

Note that for datetime objects, if you don't see the hour when they're all 00:00:00, that's not pandas. That's iPython notebook trying to make things look pretty.

Comment: This one does not work for me, it complains: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values

Comment: you may have to do `df[col] = pd.to_datetime(df[col])` first to convert your column to date time objects.

Comment: The issue with this answer is that it converts the column to `dtype = object` which takes up considerably more memory than a true `datetime dtype` in pandas.

Comment: This person didn't say anything about the size of the dataset, or about parquet.

Answer (score 12):

If you want to get the DATE and not DATETIME format:

```
df["id_date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["id_date"]).dt.date
```

Comment: I agree with @Asclepius. I've had a lot more issues with using `.dt.date` than just converting to datetime first.

Answer (score 7):

Another way to do this and this works well if you have multiple columns to convert to datetime.

```
cols = ['date1','date2']
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(pd.to_datetime)
```

Comment: Question ask for date not datetime.

Comment: @MarkAndersen aslong as you have `date` only values in your columns, convertion to datetime will retain pertaining information only. If you explicity convert using `df['datetime_col'].dt.date` that will result to an `object` dtype; loss in memory management.

Comment: There is no reason to use `.apply` here, considering a direct use of `pd.to_datetime` works.

Answer (score 2):

It may be the case that dates need to be converted to a different frequency. In this case, I would suggest setting an index by dates.

```
#set an index by dates
df.set_index(['time'], drop=True, inplace=True)
```

After this, you can more easily convert to the type of date format you will need most. Below, I sequentially convert to a number of date formats, ultimately ending up with a set of daily dates at the beginning of the month.

```
#Convert to daily dates
df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(data=df.index)

#Convert to monthly dates
df.index = df.index.to_period(freq='M')

#Convert to strings
df.index = df.index.strftime('%Y-%m')

#Convert to daily dates
df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(data=df.index)
```

For brevity, I don't show that I run the following code after each line above:

```
print(df.index)
print(df.index.dtype)
print(type(df.index))
```

This gives me the following output:

```
Index(['2013-01-01', '2013-01-02', '2013-01-03'], dtype='object', name='time')
object
<class 'pandas.core.indexes.base.Index'>

DatetimeIndex(['2013-01-01', '2013-01-02', '2013-01-03'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='time', freq=None)
datetime64[ns]
<class 'pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex'>

PeriodIndex(['2013-01', '2013-01', '2013-01'], dtype='period[M]', name='time', freq='M')
period[M]
<class 'pandas.core.indexes.period.PeriodIndex'>

Index(['2013-01', '2013-01', '2013-01'], dtype='object')
object
<class 'pandas.core.indexes.base.Index'>

DatetimeIndex(['2013-01-01', '2013-01-01', '2013-01-01'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
datetime64[ns]
<class 'pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex'>
```

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness, another option, which might not be the most straightforward one, a bit similar to the one proposed by @SSS, but using rather the datetime library is:

```
import datetime
df["Date"] = df["Date"].apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%d-%m').date())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 #   Column          Non-Null Count   Dtype         
---  ------          --------------   -----         
 0   startDay        110526 non-null  object
 1   endDay          110526 non-null  object

import pandas as pd

df['startDay'] = pd.to_datetime(df.startDay)

df['endDay'] = pd.to_datetime(df.endDay)

 #   Column          Non-Null Count   Dtype         
---  ------          --------------   -----         
 0   startDay        110526 non-null  datetime64[ns]
 1   endDay          110526 non-null  datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: No, this converts it to a 'datetime64[ns]' type not a 'date' type. Those are different things.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pandas.to_datetime()

Answer (score -1):

Try to convert one of the rows into timestamp using the pd.to_datetime function and then use .map to map the formular to the entire column