# Python - format date values when exporting to excel

Tags: python, excel, format

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
          columns=["A", "B", "C"], 
          data=[['2017-01-01',np.nan, "ok"], ['2017-02-01',8,"fine"], ['2017-03-01',100,np.nan]])
df1.to_excel('test.xlsx', index=False)
```

[image]

I have a dataframe that column is string. I want to export the df to excel and make column A the date type with the format DDMMMYYYY (i.e. instead of '2017-01-01' I need '01JAN2017').

I have tried two things that they don't work:

```
df1['A'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['A']).dt.strftime('%d%b%Y')
```

or

```
df1['A'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['A'], format="%d%b%Y")
```

How to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16852911/how-do-i-convert-dates-in-a-pandas-data-frame-to-a-date-data-type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i had a similar use case. i used pandas and [arrow](http://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/arrow)!

maybe something like this?

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import arrow

df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    columns=["A", "B", "C"],
    data=[
        ['2017-01-01',np.nan, "ok"],
        ['2017-02-01',8,"fine"],
        ['2017-03-01',100,np.nan]
    ]
)

df1['A'] = df1['A'].apply(
    lambda val: arrow.get(val).format("DDMMMYYYY").upper()
)

df1.to_excel('test.xlsx', index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Excel, format column A as a custom format:

```
dd*mmm*yyyy
```

The stars should allow for no spaces or operators to appear between the dates elements.

Also, [read this](https://superuser.com/questions/730827/formatting-an-excel-date-without-space-between-elements) for another take on formatting.

Answer (score -1):

You can first parse it to datetime object and then convert it to required format

```
from datetime import datetime
df1['A'] = datetime.strptime(df1['A'], '%Y-%m-%d').strftime("%d%b%Y").upper()
```

Comment: Thanks Zohaib. I got this error message: "TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be string, not Series". Any idea how to resolve this issue?

Comment: from your question, it seems that `df1['A']` is your date string. So find the expression for your date str and pass this in place of `df1['A']`