# Compare two dataframes and delete not same dates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes and want to compare them and delete the days in the df2 which are not the same as in df1. I tried to use:

```
df2[~df2.Date.isin(df1.Date)]
```

but this does not work and getting an empty dataframe. df2 should look like df1. The dataframe's looks like the following:

```
df1
        Date
0    20-12-16
1    21-12-16
2    22-12-16
3    23-12-16
4    27-12-16
5    28-12-16
6    29-12-16
7    30-12-16
8    02-01-17
9    03-01-17
10   04-01-17
11   05-01-17
12   06-01-17

df2

         Date
0    20-12-16
1    21-12-16
2    22-12-16
3    23-12-16
4    24-12-16
5    25-12-16
6    26-12-16
7    27-12-16
8    28-12-16
9    29-12-16
10   30-12-16
11   31-12-16
12   01-01-17
13   02-01-17
14   03-01-17
15   04-01-17
16   05-01-17
17   06-01-17
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems `dtypes` are different. For comparing need same.

Check it by:

```
print (df1.Date.dtype)
print (df2.Date.dtype)
```

and then convert if necessary:

```
df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'])
df2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date'])
```

I add another 2 solutions - first with [`numpy.in1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) and second with [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html), because need default inner join:

```
 df = df2[np.in1d(df2.Date, df1.Date)]
print (df)
         Date
0  2016-12-20
1  2016-12-21
2  2016-12-22
3  2016-12-23
7  2016-12-27
8  2016-12-28
9  2016-12-29
10 2016-12-30
13 2017-01-02
14 2017-01-03
15 2017-01-04
16 2017-01-05
17 2017-01-06
```

---

```
df = df1.merge(df2, on='Date')
print (df)
         Date
0  2016-12-20
1  2016-12-21
2  2016-12-22
3  2016-12-23
7  2016-12-27
8  2016-12-28
9  2016-12-29
10 2016-12-30
13 2017-01-02
14 2017-01-03
15 2017-01-04
16 2017-01-05
17 2017-01-06
```

Sample:

```
d1 = {'Date': ['20-12-16', '21-12-16', '22-12-16', '23-12-16', '27-12-16', '28-12-16', '29-12-16', '30-12-16', '02-01-17', '03-01-17', '04-01-17', '05-01-17', '06-01-17']}
d2 = {'Date': ['20-12-16', '21-12-16', '22-12-16', '23-12-16', '24-12-16', '25-12-16', '26-12-16', '27-12-16', '28-12-16', '29-12-16', '30-12-16', '31-12-16', '01-01-17', '02-01-17', '03-01-17', '04-01-17', '05-01-17', '06-01-17']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(d1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(d2)
```

---

```
print (df1.Date.dtype)
object

print (df2.Date.dtype)
object

df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'], format='%d-%m-%y')
df2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date'], format='%d-%m-%y')
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer. when using print I receive an object, convertion helps to convert it into datetime64[ns]. when trying to compare the dataframes i still receive an empty dataframe. Furthermore I want the dates which are equal not the non-equal ones.

Comment: thanks a lot. it seems to work but the output which I receive should be the same dates as df1 when comparing df1 and df2. Is it clear? I am not sure what Iam doing wrong or misunderstand?

Comment: @MCM - Problem is with your sample too? What is your pandas version? `print (pd.show_versions())`.

Comment: the version I used is pandas: 0.20.2. Why are you sking?

Comment: Hmmm, I have same. Problem is with my sample data too?

Comment: I can reproduce the example above from you. But the output should be as the following: 

0    20-12-16
1    21-12-16
2    22-12-16
3    23-12-16
4    27-12-16
5    28-12-16
6    29-12-16
7    30-12-16
8    02-01-17
9    03-01-17
10   04-01-17
11   05-01-17
12   06-01-17

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148308/discussion-between-mcm-and-jezrael).

Comment: I check another answer - do you need filter only same dates which are in both dataframes?

Comment: yes. Comparing two dataframes df1 and df2 and delete the non euqual dates from df2 and put that into a new dataframe. Is it clearer?

Comment: So sorry, need remove `~` and use another answer.

Comment: I decide to change my solution to add another 2 with same output as `df2[df2.Date.isin(df1.Date)]`

Comment: Thanks this small piece :). It seems to work. The only problem is that dates somehow converted wrongly:          Date
0  2016-12-20
1  2016-12-21
2  2016-12-22
3  2016-12-23
7  2016-12-27
8  2016-12-28
9  2016-12-29
10 2016-12-30
13 2017-02-01
14 2017-03-01
15 2017-04-01
16 2017-05-01
17 2017-06-01

look starting from jan, feb etc

Comment: What does mean wrongly? I thought days and months are swapped, but it seems correct.

Comment: yes this is the problem, but why it get swapped? In the other two example it is the same. How can that be prevented?

Comment: You can specify parameter format `df2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date'], format='%d-%m-%y')`

Comment: I t it but seems not to work. I tried it before. Mybe just making something wrong. Can you update the example above?

Comment: Give me a second.

Comment: OK, I do it. And I get also same data as df1, so it means `df1.Date` are subset of `df2.Date`. I think it is correct.

Comment: what do you mean? So I receive the following: The code looks like the following: 

df1 = pd.DataFrame(d1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(d2)
df2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date'], format='%d-%m-%y')
df = df2[np.in1d(df2.Date, df1.Date)]

Output:
         Date
0  2016-12-20
1  2016-12-21
2  2016-12-22
3  2016-12-23
7  2016-12-27
8  2016-12-28
9  2016-12-29
10 2016-12-30
13 2017-02-01
14 2017-03-01
15 2017-04-01
16 2017-05-01
17 2017-06-01

which the january dates should be:
13 2017-01-02
14 2017-01-03
15 2017-01-04
16 2017-01-05
17 2017-01-06

is it clearer?

Comment: It seems all is OK. You need filter `df2` and as output dates which are in df1 and too in df2. So your output show you have all data frm df1 also in df2, so output is same as df1.

Comment: yes the output is right. But I dont understand why tthe dates get cverted wrongly?

Comment: Do you think without parameter format? Answer is pandas try guess pattern of datetime and something it happens.

Comment: what do you mean? I used: df2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date'], format='%d-%m-%y') and then do the comparison: df = df2[np.in1d(df2.Date, df1.Date)]. Do I miss something?

Comment: No, I think if not define parameter `format` in `to_datetime` pandas try find pattern of datetime. But now it is all OK. I am really happy it works for you ;)

Comment: actually it does not work :(. Also by defining the format. Thats why I am confused

Comment: Hmmm, what does not work? Do you have different output?

Comment: If I compare January I receive the following:      
Date
13 2017-02-01
14 2017-03-01
15 2017-04-01
16 2017-05-01
17 2017-06-01
But it should be:
         Date
13 2017-01-02
14 2017-01-03
15 2017-01-04
16 2017-01-05
17 2017-01-06
.Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: Hmmm, what is `print (df2.Date.dtype)` and `print (df1.Date.dtype)` before converting to datetime? both are objects?

Comment: both are datetime64[ns]. The full code looks like the following: 
d1 = {'Date': pd.to_datetime(['20-12-16', '21-12-16,...])}
d2 = {'Date': pd.to_datetime(['20-12-16', '21-12-16', '22-12-16',...])}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(d1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(d2)
print(df1.Date.dtype)
print(df2.Date.dtype)
df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'], format='%d-%m-%y')
df2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date'], format='%d-%m-%y')
df = df2[np.in1d(df2.Date, df1.Date)]
print(df)

Comment: I think I see problem

Comment: need `d1 = {'Date': ['20-12-16', '21-12-16,...]} d2 = {'Date': ['20-12-16', '21-12-16', '22-12-16',...]}` not `d1 = {'Date': pd.to_datetime(['20-12-16', '21-12-16,...])} d2 = {'Date': pd.to_datetime(['20-12-16', '21-12-16', '22-12-16',...])}`, because you double convert to datetimes one column.

Comment: Yes you are right! Now it seems to work. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is from logic. You want to select the df2 date that are df1. So you should write

```
df2[df2.Date.isin(df1.Date)]
```

not the contrary of the boolean where comparison/inclusion in df1 is true

You could also obtain the same result with

```
set(b.Date)-(set(b.Date)-set(a.Date))
```

Which should then be used through:

```
pd.DataFrame(sorted((set(b.Date)-(set(b.Date)-set(a.Date)))), columns=["Date"] )
```

While the sorting is not optimal and you may change it in pandas by better logic.

```
 df = pd.DataFrame(list((set(b.Date)-(set(b.Date)-set(a.Date)))), columns=["Date"] ) 
 df.Date = [date.date() for date in df.Date]
```

or
     df.Date.dt.date

(see [How do I convert dates in a Pandas data frame to a 'date' data type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16852911/how-do-i-convert-dates-in-a-pandas-data-frame-to-a-date-data-type))

Comment: Thanks a lot. I don't want the different dates but more comparing two dataframes df1 and df2 and delete the non euqual dates from df2 and put that into a new dataframe. Is it clearer?

Comment: Yes it is. So that's exactly what my answer do. df2.Date.isin(df1.Date) returns a boolean where True is for dates of df2 similar to df1. So you boolean index these directly into df2.

Comment: So the answer above helped. Thanks for the help.