# TypeError: Cannot compare type 'Timestamp' with type 'date'

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

The problem is in *line 22* :

`if start_date <= data_entries.iloc[j, 1] <= end_date:`

where I want to compare the `start_date` and `end_date` portion to `data_entries.iloc[j, 1]` which is accessing a column of the pandas dataframe. I converted the column to *datetime* using,

`data_entries['VOUCHER DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(data_entries['VOUCHER DATE'], format="%m/%d/%Y")`

But I am unsure how to convert it to *date*.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

entries_csv = "C:\\Users\\Pops\\Desktop\\Entries.csv"

data_entries = pd.read_csv(entries_csv)
data_entries['VOUCHER DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(data_entries['VOUCHER DATE'], format="%m/%d/%Y")

start_date = datetime.date(2018, 4, 1)
end_date = datetime.date(2018, 10, 30)

    for j in range(0, len(data_entries)):
        if start_date <= data_entries.iloc[j, 1] <= end_date:
             print('Hello')
```

Comment: please provide [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Check this.
https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Comment: @pratikmankar I was referring to this earlier actually. My problem is the `pd.to_datetime()` of pandas. I believe there is no `pd.to_date()` equivalent. The link below only converts to datetime, but based on my code, it does not work with `datetime.date()` when you try to compare them. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16852911/how-do-i-convert-dates-in-a-pandas-data-frame-to-a-date-data-type

Comment: you could `data_entries['VOUCHER DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(data_entries['VOUCHER DATE'], format="%m/%d/%Y").dt.date`

Comment: @MarcSantos - It is pandas version related problem, you can check [this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#whatsnew-0231-fixed-regressions).

Comment: @moshevi it works thanks

Comment: @jezrael will look into it thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

this converts it to date:

```
data_entries['VOUCHER DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(data_entries['VOUCHER DATE'], format="%m/%d/%Y").dt.date
```

however i would not recommend filtering like this.
this is much faster

```
data_entries[data_entries['VOUCHER DATE'].between(start_date, end_date)]
```

read this [article](https://engineering.upside.com/a-beginners-guide-to-optimizing-pandas-code-for-speed-c09ef2c6a4d6)

Answer (score 10):

Just use `pd.Timestamp` objects without any conversion:

```
start_date = pd.Timestamp('2018-04-01')
end_date = pd.Timestamp('2018-10-30')

res = data_entries[data_entries['VOUCHER DATE'].between(start_date, end_date)]
```

**Explanation**

Don't use `datetime.datetime` or `datetime.date` objects in Pandas series. This is inefficient because you lose vectorised functionality. The benefit of `pd.Timestamp` objects is you can utilize vectorised functionality for calculations. As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49758140/9209546):

> `numpy.datetime64` is essentially a thin wrapper an int64. It has
>   almost no date/time specific functionality.
>
> `pd.Timestamp` is a wrapper around a numpy.datetime64. It is backed by
>   the same int64 value, but supports the entire `datetime.datetime`
>   interface, along with useful pandas-specific functionality.

Comment: Thanks for this as well. Really helpful